# Determining if SMS is binary or text

Tags: android, binary, sms, android-5.1.1-lollipop, pdu

I have a default SMS messenger Android app that will receive binary and plain text messages. I need to determine if the received SMS is in binary or text to know how to send a message back to the original sender.

On 5.1 I can check the MessageBody for null. Null means it's binary. On 5.1.1 I don't see the same results. The MessageBody has junk from incorrect encoding. I receive the error `messageBody is other binary data format encodingType=2` In the console.

Is there another way to determine if a SmsMessage is binary?

Thanks

Comment: Encoding type 2 means its binary (in some cases also 4). Check for encoding type parameter if you have it, which will tell you what kind of
message is (e.g. 0 is gsm 7bit, 3 is latin1, 8 is ucs2(utf16) etc

Comment: SMPP v3.4 specs, section 5.2.19 data_coding